# Sort varchar with alpha numeric and special character values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a invoice_number field as `varchar(20)`

I have the select query as

```
SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY case isnumeric(invoice_number) 
                                       when 1 then convert(bigint,invoice_num)
                                       else 99999999999999999999 
                                  end) As id, 
       name,
       submit_date,
       invoice_number,
       invoice_total,
       currency_code
FROM vw_invoice_report
```

which works fine for a few scenarios but I couldn't make it work for all the the `invoice_number` values as below

```
f8ad2a28ddad4f6aa4df
0B849D69741145379079
20190313176617593442
ATOctober2000Promise
00100001010000000061
E285567EF0D0885E9160
SC1805000123000293
1999bernstyin2010
20600006307FFGMG
REVISED INVOICE F...
1111-2222(changzhou)
667339, 667340, 6...
18.12733562GAGA L...
IN-US01235055    ...
SSR-USD/426/2019 - 2
Nanny; Park Doug
184034
376840
376847-1
72692
72691
72690
72689
```

Am getting `Error converting data type varchar to bigint.` for some of the above data, can someone please help me make it work for the above test data?

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that some of your invoice numbers (for example `20190313176617593442`) are too large for the `BIGINT` data type. You can work around this by keeping the values as strings, and left padding with `0` the numeric ones out to 20 digits for sorting. For example:

```
SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY case isnumeric(invoice_number) 
                                       when 1 then REPLACE(STR(invoice_number, 20), ' ', '0') 
                                       else '99999999999999999999'
                                  end) As id,
```

Demo (also showing converted invoice numbers) on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/81433/6)

**Update**

Based on OP comments and additional values to be sorted, this query should satisfy that requirement:

```
SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY case 
                                       when isnumeric(invoice_number) = 1 then RIGHT('00000000000000000000' + REPLACE(invoice_number, '.', ''), 20) 
                                       when invoice_number like '%[0-9]-[0-9]%' and invoice_number not like '%[^0-9]' then REPLACE(STR(REPLACE(invoice_number, '-', '.'), 20), ' ', '0')
                                       else '99999999999999999999'
                                  end) As id,
       invoice_number
FROM vw_invoice_report
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8dc1b/25)

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b0f8c/1 your works for most of the except the entries with period(.) can you please check the SQLFiddle with the additional  values

Comment: @RanPaul how do you want the invoice numbers with `.`. in them to sort? e.g. should `61.913` be treated as `61` or `61913` or `99999999999999999999`?

Comment: it should be treated as 61913, also sort order for entries with dash(-) is deterministic
the expected out for the entries with dash is `376845-1,376846-1,376847-1,376848-1` but the order is different with your solution, is there a way to sort such entries? 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8dc1b/1

Comment: @RanPaul should `376845-1` sort before or after `200000` or `600000`?

Comment: `376845-1` should be sorted after `200000`

Comment: @RanPaul see my edit. I think that should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I am thinking this might do what you want:

```
row_number() over (order by (case when isnumeric(invoicenumber) = 1
                                  then len(invoicenumber)
                                  else 99999
                                  end
                            ),
                            invoicenumber
                  )
```

Comment: how do I order it by `desc`? also whats the purpose of `99999`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff has it.  He's effectively changing the sort by number if it is numeric, and text if it is text.  The 99999 is a stand-in for the non-numeric length (you'll never have a number longer than that many digits, so those will always go after the numeric values).  You can place desc after the first and second order by's if you want it descending.